# Setup developer tools for "Brave" browser

Tags: browser, interface, console, developer-tools

I am using the "Brave" browser and when I open the developer tools, they open in a separate window. Does anyone know how I can get them to appear on the same page, like in Chrome/Vivaldi/etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently not supported.

See [Allow attaching developer tools (F12) to the tab frame](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/3555).

Comment: Very unfortunate - I'd love to use Brave because I like everything about it but this is back-breaking.

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation. Would use Brave but not being able to have the dev tools docked within the tab it belongs to, it's a huge deal.

Answer (score 3):

I (inadvertently) discovered that while `F12` opens the developer tools in a separate window, `Shift-F8` opens and toggles it in the same way Chrome and FireFox do with `F12`.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or a feature...

I am testing out the most recent stable version of Brave, 0.18.23 with Windows 10.

**UPDATE**

I may have jumped the gun here... it *LOOKS* like the browser tools, but I can't seem to get the normal HTML display to access the source elements.  Rather, it seems to show the internal "guts" of Brave interpreting the page.  Not very useful for a developer, unless you are a browser developer.

Way to go, people at Brave!  You find docking the developer tools really useful, and so do we!  Please fix this!

Comment: `Shift+F8` open the built in developer tools for debugging the renderer process. See [Debugging](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/docs/debugging.md).

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7 too. But yea, the web-page sources aren't available and it doesn't show all network messages sent...

Answer (score 2):

New versions are built on [Chromium](https://brave.com/new-brave-browser-release-available-for-general-download/) 70 and it works great. Comes with the standard Chrome developer tools. Vue works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Brave does have the options to dock the window:

Click with the right mouse button on any part of the webpage you want to inspect > in the menu choose inspect > A docker appears: at top right area, notice the three-points-button, click it > the dockside options appear: first one is separate window for the inspector window, in the tree other options the inspector options are docked in the same window as the webpage you are inspecting.

[options for docking the developper window on the upper right corner of inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzuvf.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).